# Component property changes not reflecting in UI

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

I have a list component and item component. The list component fetches data from a server and uses the item component to render each piece of data.
Am using firebase to push data changes from server to client.

This is the list component

```
angular.module('app')
  .component('orderList', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/orders/list.html',
    controller: function($rootScope, $scope, $element, $attrs, loading, popup, toast, orders) {
      var vm = this;

      vm.orders = [];

      vm.$onInit = function() {
        orders.all().
        then(function(data) {
          vm.orders = data;
        })

        firebase.database().ref('/orders/10').
        on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {
          var order = vm.orders.filter(function(o) { return 0.id == snapshot.key })[0];
          if(order) {
            var index = vm.orders.indexOf(order);
            _.merge(vm.orders[index], snapshot.val());
          }
        })
      }
    }
  })
```

and the item component

```
angular.module('app')
  .component('orderItem', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/orders/item.html',
    bindings: {
      item: '<'
    },
    controller: function($rootScope, $scope, $element, $attrs) {
      var vm = this;
    }
  })
```

The list component html

```
<order-item ng-repeat="order in $ctrl.orders" item="order"></order-item>
```

The item component html

```
<div class="item-image"><img src="img/drawer-header-bg.png"></div>
<div class="item-status">{{ $ctrl.item.status }}</div>
```

When the 'child_changed' event is triggered and the item data is merge with data from firebase, the view doesn't update.

Comment: I don't see template attached to `orderList` component, you should add `templateUrl: 'list.component.html'` over there

Comment: @PankajParkar updated the question with the templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're changing scope data inside an event which is outside of angular's context.

Like with any event ($scope.$on...etc;) you need to update the scope:

```
$scope.$apply();
```